# GML: instance_create not working, object is not being put into the room

Tags: game-development, gml

I'm trying to make a game where spikes fall from the sky and the player has to move from side to side to dodge them. The object I'm trying to get to move down from the top of the screen is named obj_spike. What I want to accomplish is the spikes spawning in at the top of the screen and moving downwards. This works if I put the objects in the room as they are, but I can't make it spawn infinitely. How do I do that? The piece of code I've been trying to use is this:

`instance_create(random_range(0,640),480,obj_spike);`

For some reason the object just doesn't create.

Comment: First you would want to make sure that your code even runs. Try adding a `show_debug_message` call next to it. Then, your code is not creating the spikes on top of the screen, it creates them at the bottom. Perhaps that's an issue too

Comment: @YellowAfterlife How do I add the call? Do I just put it on the line below?